How do #1 and #2 work in a function defined by 2 variables?
Can someone please explain the function of #1 and #2 in a pure random function of two variables?
For example, if I had something like:
function[x_, y_]:= (some function in terms of x,y, #1, #2)
For some random lists x and y. Apologies, I don't have a good enough understanding of the use of #1 and #2 to form a coherent example yet).
At first, I was thinking that maybe #1 and #2 represent the lists x and y respectively but this doesn't make sense to me as surely you would just use x and y to serve this purpose.
Then I thought that #1 and #2 represent Table[x[[i]],{i,Length[x]}] and Table[y[[j]],{j,Length[y]}] respectively. But again this doesn't make a lot of sense to me.
If anyone could either give me a good example of their usage in a function with two variables or explain the theory of them, that would be great. I have looked at the pure random function explanation on "An elementary introduction to the Wolfram Language" and did not find any clarity.

You would typically only use the Slot expressions (#, ##, #1, etc) in Function expressions. If you're using SetDelayed (i.e. :=) with named arguments, you just use the argument names and there's no need for the Slot expressions.

Is this a general question about Slot just for understanding, or are you having trouble building the actual function you want? If you need help solving a specific problem, then provide more context/details and we can point you in the right direction.

Hi, it was a general question about understanding Slot. I think you have just answered my question. So in SetDelayed functions, using #1,#2 is unnecessary and we can just use the named variables instead? I have seen SetDelayed functions that are in terms of f[x_,y_] := ..... where the  ..... is in terms of x,y,#1 and #2 (see example in comment below answer by Ulrich Neumann). However, from your answer it appears that the #1, #2 is arbitary and we can write everything in terms of x,y ?

I wouldn't say the #1 and #2 are arbitrary. They are important to the specific Function expression that is being used for DeleteDuplicates. It's just that those Slots don't have anything to do with x and y (directly). The existence of those Slot expressions is sort of "accidental" in terms of defining f.

You could have rewritten the Function being used in DeleteDuplicates to use named arguments instead of Slot. Something like this Function[{a, b}, MemberQ[Outer[Plus, List[a], x], b]]. The x still refers to the argument passed to f. The a and b are now arguments that will be bound as needed when DeleteDuplicates does its work. So, you can write everything in terms of named arguments instead of Slots, but that's slightly different than what you said.

This makes sense in the context that you have used. However, I am a little confused because this seems to require that your Function has two arguments {a,b}. However, my DeleteDuplicates uses y, which doesn't obviously split into a and b to be used in the function?

Ah. Now we're talking about a completely different topic. The test function that you pass to DeleteDuplicates needs two arguments, because DeleteDuplicates looks at pairs of elements to determine if it should delete one of them. If I want to delete duplicates from {1,2,1,3}, I need to scan that list and compare pairs. So, 1 == 2? nope, keep them. 1 == 1? Yep, delete the second 1. 1 == 3? Nope, keep. 2 == 3? Nope, keep. Each == comparison needs two arguments. The default test is ==, but if you provide your own test function, it will be used the same way to scan the pairs.

Ah okay, I think this makes sense! So the example of f[x_,y_] := DeleteDuplicates[y, MemberQ[Outer[Plus,{#1}, x],#2]&] is simply checking whether ($y_{1} + {x}$) is a member of ${y}$ and then storing these values in a list, checking whether ($y_{2} + {x}$) is a member of ${y}$ and then adding these values to our list etc. until we have checked if $(y_{n}+{x})$ is a member of ${y}$ and added these values to our list. And then once this is done, we delete any duplicates from the list of all ${y_{i} + x | y_{i} + x \in {y}}$?

I would like to know where you got that example from. I think it's defective. Or it expects a very specialized form of input that I haven't yet figured out. So, I'm not going to try to explain what it's supposed to do. I could tell you what it is actually doing for specific, simple inputs, but it's kinda nonsense. You can see this yourself by using Trace. Try something like Trace[f[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]]. It looks like a big no-op that just returns the same value as the second argument. I stopped trying to reverse engineer what kind of inputs it actually expects (assuming it's correct).

#1 is a placeholder for the first functionargument, # 2 for the second.
For example
function=#1 #2^2&

defines a function for two arguments
function[x,y]  (*x y^2*)

Hope it helps!

I understand in the context you have just used but I have seen before where they have something like f[x_,y_] := DeleteDuplicates[y, MemberQ[Outer[Plus,{#1}, x],#2]&]  this uses both x,y, and #1,#2. What is the point of using #1,#2 if they essentially just stand for x and y? I am specifically interested in functions that use all arguments x,y,##1,#2 in the same line of code

In that case, this part of the expression, MemberQ[Outer[Plus, {#1}, x], #2] &, is an anonymous function that is an argument to DeleteDuplicates. So, the #1 and #2 don't refer to x and y. They refer to some "future" arguments that will be passed to this function as DeleteDuplicates does its work.

@am567 #1 and #2 do not stand for x and y here. They are unnamed arguments of MemberQ[Outer[Plus,{#1}, x],#2]&, which is a Function in itself.

... and this & shorthand version would be equivalent to Function[{a, b}, MemberQ[Outer[Plus, {a}, x], b]], for instance.

Okay, so they would actually be taking different arguments from y in this case as that is the argument specifed as the list we are checking against in delete duplicates?

You are effectively defining a new function inside the function f. This function is called as a test for numerous pairs of two elements DeleteDuplicates, with #1 as the first one and #2 as the second. Functions as arguments, often expressed in the & form are a very typical thing in Wolfram Language, as it tends to exhibit traits of functional programming where functions are treated as "first class citizens". Other such languages are LISP and its derivatives, which stem from lambda calculus.
